# Weird Laptop Power Connector

Tags: laptop, power-supply

I just received a laptop without a power cord. I decided to go out and buy a power cord, but This type of DC jack is completely foreign to me. Does anybody know the name of it, or where I might be able to find one (ex: what other devices use it)

**EDIT: computer model: "ECS model no. A928"**
[image]

[image]

Comment: The picture quality is a little potato, and it looks like there's a java hiding in there. More information on what the laptop actually is might be helpful, but that looks ginormous,

Comment: a java? Yes, sorry about the picture quality, i currently don't have a better camera than my laptop's built in one. And yes, it is a *very* old laptop. Unfortunately, i currently don't have the model number, but i will try to get it as soon as possible. The small dot on the bottom is in fact a connector. It's 3 metal prongs in a "micky mouse" shape

Comment: Small scrap collecting humanoids. Tend to steal whatever isn't stolen. Oh wait, that's a Jawa... There's got to be a sticker *somewhere* that tells you what it si.

Comment: Yeah, it does have a model, but I currently do not have access to the computer. I will try to get hold of it again tomorrow.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek edited the question to include the model

Comment: Here is an image of the connector: https://d2mm29uzm8xyaw.cloudfront.net/i/LITE-ON-PA-1900-05-AC-Adapter-Laptop-PA-1900-05-b-36019.jpg (found on http://pchub.com/uph/model/0--3962-1/A928-parts.html )

Comment: Note: I found multiple shops selling matching ac adapters just by googling for `ECS A928 ac adapter`.

Comment: yeah, once i figured out the model number it was easy to find.

Answer (score 0):

I think is a [IEC60320](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320#C7.2FC8_coupler) C7 or C8 connector.

It used to be very common on portable tape recorders.

Comment: sorry, there's not much size comparison, but this is not the connector. True, it bears a vague resemblance in shape, but it is much smaller.

Comment: With three prongs more likely a  C5/C6. Does look a little like a cloverleaf